# Progress Dialog is not showing while retrieving photos from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, progressdialog, firebase-storage

As title says, my progress dialog is not showing when i try to retrieve some photos from Firebase storage.
Here my code :

```
progress = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading...", "Please wait...", true);
//Retrieve photos from storage
mDatabase.child("TopCommentPhotos").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
        Random r = new Random();
        int random = r.nextInt((size+1) - 1) + 1;

        int count=0;
        for(DataSnapshot child: children) {
            count = count+1;
            if (count == random){
                progress.dismiss();
                ImageModel imageModel = child.getValue(ImageModel.class);
                String downloadUrl = imageModel.getUrl();
               // Display photo
                Glide.with(getActivity())
                        .load(downloadUrl)
                        .into(mImageView);

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```

Thanks for help

Comment: if you remove the code `//Retrieve photos from storage`, does the dialog show?

Comment: yeah it work well (sure if i add something to do)

Comment: Where do you set the value of `size`? Shouldn't it be `dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()`?

Comment: Yes you are right, thanks for it i will use it, now hope to solve my problem of progress dialog?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
                                Random r = new Random();
                                int random = r.nextInt((size+1) - 1) + 1;

                                int count=0;
                                for(DataSnapshot child: children) {
                                    count = count+1;
                                    if (count == random){

                                        ImageModel imageModel = child.getValue(ImageModel.class);
                                        String downloadUrl = imageModel.getUrl();
                                       // Display photo 
                                        Glide.with(getActivity()) 
                                                .load(downloadUrl)
                                                .into(mImageView); 

                                    } 
                                } 
progress.dismiss(); 


                            }
```

and,

```
@Override 
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
progress.dismiss();
                      }
```